# How to leverage Hangfire in case of multiple microservices hosted in Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: microservices, azure-aks, hangfire, .net-7.0

I have three .NET 7 Microservices hosted within Azure Kubernetes Service. I have few background tasks that needs to be managed via Hangfire. Implementation of Hangfire in case of monolithic application is straight forward but when it comes to microservice implementation it looks to be a challenging and there are no concrete examples available.

In my case Microservice B acts as Hangfire server and the database linked with this microservice acts as Hangfire job storage. Both Microservice A and Microservice C act as Hangfire client applications. In short they will be initiating few process which needs to be processed by the Microservice B (Hangfire Server).

[image]

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance